# How to get on a minecraft server that you are currently connected to on another computer

Tags: authentication, networking, minecraft

Basically, if I'm connected to a minecraft server on computer A, then can I connect to the same server on computer B without server noiticing disconnecting on computer A and reconnecting on computer B? Back in 2020 I think there was an exploit, witch allowed to get anyones session id and join the server that they were playing on, and the game was kicking the legit player, and letting the hacker join, but now when I try to connect to a server that I'm connected to on computer A on computer B, then I get such message:
[image: error message screenshot]

**EDIT:** I'm trying to join 2b2t.org on minecraft version 1.12.2 using impact cheats.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to connect from a second computer it allowed me to connect and play normally, but it logged me out from the first computer and the first computer showed the below screen.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oqCn.png

Comment: Yeah, that's what was happening in that exploit that I mentioned, and the expected result. Maybe it doesn't work for me because I use 1.12.2, impact cheats or that I'm joining 2b2t.org server?